# requestLocationUpdates vs Location Listener

Tags: android, gps, android-maps, android-location

What is the difference between using a location manager object with requestLocationUpdates() vs just using a LocationListener? do they both do the same thing and work the same way?  Whats the advantage of one over the other?

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_provicer, 0, 0, new LocationListener()){
//all appropriate methods here
}
```

VS.

```
LocationListener myLocationListener = New LocationListener(){
// all appropriate methods here
}
```

Comment: When I say technically wrong, its not wrong enough to downvote :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is technically incorrect. LocationManager registers a listener via requestLocationUpdates. The listener is the callback when your location manager realizes that the timeout OR distance travel has occurred. In your case the location listener will be called immediately.

But beware, location manager request updates with **0,0** parameters are **not** known to be instantaneous. Sometimes there may be a delay.

So your question on **what is the difference** is incorrect. Its like asking what is the difference between `Print this` and `System.out.println()` :)

Comment: Ok so its not an either or type of thing.  I use my LocationManager object to requestlocationUpdates() then i handle these updates using a LocationListener?

Comment: Yes you are correct. But LocationListener is a interface, so you need to implement it. And provide this object reference to requestLocationUpdates. Correct.

Comment: Thank you for clearing this up. didnt realize how critical location listers were to handle changes in location. also thought that Location Listeners were useful on their own when they infact need a location manager to be used.